# How to point one resource (a SolidColorBrush) at another

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, resourcedictionary

I set up a load of SolidColorBrush and LinearGradientBrush resources in a ResourceDictionary. I used these as I was restyling several controls for use in our application.

Now I have a bunch of other external brushes that I have to use for a variation on our app. These are also set up in a ReseourceDictionary.

Is it possible to point my brush resources at the new resources in another dictionary, something  similar to the "BasedOn" attribute of Styles?

Something like this, conceptually at least:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyDataGridHeaderBrush" Binding="HeaderBrushDefinedElsewhere"/>
```

...or is this kind of thing not possible, in which case I have to simply go do a Find/Replace and replace all my brush names with the new brush names?

Thanks in advance,

AT

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I agree with what Rachel said, but if you have to base it on an existing SolidColorBrush, you can do it with the following:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyDataGridHeaderBrush" 
                 Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource HeaderBrushDefinedElsewhere}, Path=Color}"/>
```

Note this just works for the "Color" attribute, you'd have to do it separately for each attribute you needed.

Comment: Brilliant! Now I can really start cascading like I want to.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I have been looking for thank you.  I might point out you are missing the closing brace ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Usually I do a static Color property in one place, and have my brushes bind to that Color.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColor" Color="#C5DBF6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkColor" Color="#FF8DB2E3"/>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FadeOutRight" EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LightColor}, Path=Color}" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarkColor}, Path=Color}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

You can also bind other SolidBrushColors to this:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LightColor}, Path=Color}" />
```

If this is referenced in another file, it might underline it because it can't find the static resource, but at runtime it will still compile providing your main resource file containing your brush definitions is loaded.

Comment: Has this functionality changed since 2011?  I'm getting an error "An object of the type System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush cannot be applied to a property that expects the type System.Windows.Media.Color" using exactly the same as the example above (i.e. gradient stops).

Comment: @Grim It might be best if you create a separate question with the XAML you are using. I don't think anything has changed, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yea it doesn't seem to work to assign a solidColorBrush to the color property unfortunately. Atleast the designer complains and refuses to update the color when changing the referenced color.

Comment: @David Sorry, I didn't notice I had the syntax of my examples wrong. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487380/302677) on here has the correct syntax, or I've updated my examples.